# header, footer divs placement in separate files

Tags: php, html

Given basic html structure:
divs: wrapper, header, content, footer - can i separate the divs through files like:

header.php

```
<body>
<div id=wrapper>
<div id=header></div>
<div id=content>
```

index.php

footer.php

```
</div><!-- End of content -->
<div id=footer></div>
</div><!-- End of wrapper -->
```

Seems that this way I can push most of unnecessary html out of the way to focus on coding content.

The problem with includes is that my wrapper and content divs starts on one file and end on another which generates eclipse editor visual warning and annoys me with it (hey mate, there's something wrong, u need to fix this... "yellow triangle with !" symbol on all folder structure)

Comment: Ignore it if you're using include, your IDE can not see the result of merged php files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP allows you to include additional files into the one currently running, with the [`include` or `require`](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp) statement.

This will allow you to have a common header and footer that are included on the server so that you only have one page returned to the browser without needing to request additional HTML pages.

**header.php**

```
<header>Place your header content here</header>
```

**footer.php**

```
<footer>Place your footer content here</footer>
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<body>

<?php include 'header.php';?>
<p>Some text.</p>
<p>Some more text.</p>
<?php include 'footer.php';?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Load the html files for header & footer from script just shown in following example.

```js
$("document").ready(function(){
    $("#header").load("header.html");
    $("#footer").load("footer.html");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
     <head>
     </head>
     <body>
          <div id="header">
               <!-- Content in header goes here -->
          </div>
          <div id="Content">
                <!-- Content -->
          </div>
          <div id="footer">
                <!-- Content in footer goes here -->
          </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this will not works with your html structure. you try to load html files to divs with ids you ever hasn't.